# why is the slider not working with this g+ feed plugin?

Tags: jquery, joomla, rss

I'm working on a joomla based website that has a very simple slider build in. I have to put a g+ feed on the sidebar, where news would appear and so far, I've only found one joomla module for g+. But when I activate this module, the slider stops working. Both are jQuery based. Could you please have a look?
The url of the website is http://geromaslan.ro/ and the plugin is http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-profiles/18627.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla uses mootools, your addon uses jQuery and the two don't play nice together by default.

After loading jQuery you *must* call the noConflict() function immediately before loading any other jQuery add-ons. Some jQuery code needs to be rewritten to not utilise the $ function directly.

Here is some useful info
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Best I can tell the extension in question is simply broken. It will fail to work on 99.9% of Joomla websites, the exceptions being where devs explicitly force Mootools to unload.